# how can I send fcm using user segment

Tags: http, flutter, postman

now I'm testing http request using POSTMAN

```
**"to": "/topics/all",   ---> ?? how can i write this line??**
"priority": "high",
"notification": {
    "title": "テスト Title",
    "body": "テスト Body"
},
"data": {

    "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
}
```

I checked status 200 ok
when I send message with firebase web page, it works well
but without firebase cloud message service, it doesn't work 
In firebase cloud message service, the targeting condition is

I'm suppose that if i can write targeting condition in http format, I can send message to my app

help me

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is key "topic"

```
{
  "topic": "all",
  "notification":{
     "title": "テスト Title",
     "body": "テスト Body"
  },
  "data":{
     "click_action": "FLUTTER_NOTIFICATION_CLICK"
  }
}
```